# Population data as grid

Tags: data-request, geospatial, demographics, europe, global

I'm looking for world/europe/switzerland population data with a grid format. For example, 1km squares and then the population in that gridpoint.

---

I found one source, http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata

> Subject: Population
>
> Description: Population density (old)
>
> Source: [CIESIN](http://www.ciesin.org/), 2000. Global gridded population database
>
> Format:   Grid
>
> Resolution: 30 seconds

But I'd like to know if there is anything more updated, and perhaps different file/db formats. The above source file format is:

> Vector data are stored as ESRI shapefiles Grid (raster) data are stored as DIVA gridfiles

That site's file format docs are down, but here's an [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20070208015322/http://www.diva-gis.org/data/gridfiles.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From NASA's Socioeconomic Data and Applications Center (SEDAC), I found this dataset: [Gridded Population of the World (GPW), v4](http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/collection/gpw-v4).

**Resolution**:

- 30 arc-second (approx 1 km) native resolution, which is aggregated to four lower resolutions:
- 2.5 arc-minute (approx 5 km)
- 15 arc-minute (approx 30 km)
- 30 arc-minute (approx 55 km)
- 1 degree (approx 110 km)

**Date**:

- > Population input data are collected at the most detailed spatial resolution available from the results of the 2010 round of Population and Housing Censuses, which occurred between 2005 and 2014.
- > All estimates of population counts and population density have also been nationally adjusted to population totals from the United Nation’s World Population Prospects: The 2015 Revision
- > The input data are extrapolated to produce population estimates for the years 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, and 2020.

**Format:**

> The raster data sets are now available in ASCII (text) format as well as in GeoTIFF format. Five of the eight raster data sets are also available in netCDF format

**Data License:**

> licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0)

Answer (score 1):

You can get data like this at [WorldPop](https://www.worldpop.org/project/categories?id=3). 
They have 100M data for individual countries and 1km data for the continents. The data are provided as a tif file.

Comment: it's a good resource, note that for Europe/Switzerland, you have to choose "Global per country" and not "individual countries"